# ExtJS: Loading multiple stores using one Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am fairly new to ExtJS so I was wondering which approach is best for displaying different views of information using one grid. This is what I'm thinking about doing. I have three different data stores that are each utilizing the proxy and returning JSON. Let's call them STORE1, STORE2 and STORE3. I'm using different stores because each one has different parameters that are being executed to be retrieved from the server. Now, I want to include three buttons, each triggering a store to be used to populate the Grid. How exactly do I specify a new store for the Grid to use after it's been instantiated? I don't see a setStore() in the Grid object so I'm not sure how to go about solving my problem. If someone could provide me some insight, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this problem.

- The first thing I would do is really think through your use case. Are you sure this is the way you want to handle your user interface? Would it make more sense to **filter** the data (either by default or by the user interaction). There are several examples of this out there. One that comes to mind is the simple task widget (not that simple) http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/simple-tasks/index.html - the top right button filter the store based on user selection. It uses one grid + one store .. but filters the data based on user selection.
- If you are set on loading data from different stores you can utilize one store to manage the view and other stores to fetch data. On load of the stores that fetch data you use loadData (or loadRecords) method to update the store that controls the view. Makes sense? Watch out for corner cases here though ..what happens if you load the same data twice? Should you use "append" option on the loadData method?

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That example has got me thinking of new things now. I really like that idea. When you were talking about filtering, were you suggesting to load ALL the data and then filtering off that? I ask because we have a lot of data and if I don't break it up, I feel like that would have a huge impact on the performance. Is this something that is done frequently? Though, I'm not sure if my way of thinking is valid.

Comment: it's up to you how to design that. i think everyone struggles with containing data. my prefered method is to page the data - so you fetch only 50 records at a time. then let users sort it (remote sort),  filter it - either through filter plugins or custom filter methods (like in the example), and finally search it. others like the infinite scrolling (via buffered store). Either way whats the point of splashing 5K records on the page? No one can consume it in any meaningful manner.

Answer (score 2):

Grid has method `bindStore`. If you need to also assign different set of columns - check `reconfigure` method

Comment: yeah this is also a good way to go. +1 Another thought is to use card layout and show the same Grid bound to 3 different stores. This will make switching between the three states faster then re-fetching data and re-configuring the view.